# Why is ISNUMERIC(',') true?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Why does the following Query in SQL return true??
I expected it to be false as it cannot be converted into an `int` or numeric value

`select ISNUMERIC(',')`

return `1`???

```
select ISNUMERIC('0,1,2')

select ISNUMERIC(',,,')
```

also returns `1`

**What could I do for strict numeric checking in SQL?**

Comment: I'm sure someone can explain this better, but ',' seems to be a valid value for the `MONEY` data type (value 0.0), and isnumeric seems to check for that type too. The contradictory thing though is that the empty string seems to return false for isnumeric but will also convert to the money value 0.0 just fine.

Answer (score 7):

Because `ISNUMERIC` answers a question that *nobody* has ever wanted to ask:

> Can this given string be converted into *any* of SQL Server's numeric data types? And I don't care *which* of those types it can or cannot be converted into.

This is why [`TRY_CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) was finally introduced into 2012 - to answer a question about a *specific* data type that you may care about.

---

For earlier versions, the best you can usually do is to use `LIKE` to identify the string patterns you *do* want to attempt to convert.

E.g. if you just want to detect digits, use `Value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`, which asks for `Value` strings that do *not* contain any character which is *not* a digit.

Comment: Any explanation for the empty string converting to money just fine but returning isnumeric=0? Bug? Feature I'm mis-understanding?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - I think that's a bug. So far as I'm aware, the empty string will actually convert to any numeric type.

Answer (score 3):

[IsNumeric returns true for "," and "."](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/302466/isnumeric-returns-true-for-and)

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 if the string can be converted to any one of ints, numeric/decimal, float, or money. In this particular case, converting ',.' to money succeeds and returns 0.0000, therefore ISNUMERIC returns 1.

[Enhancement to ISNUMERIC](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/177308/enhancement-to-isnumeric):

> We have now added a new scalar function called [`TRY_CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) that will allow you to convert from a string to type using optional style. If the conversion fails then it will return NULL. The signature of the function is:
>
> ```
> TRY_CONVERT(data_type[(length)], expression [,style])
> ```

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

Microsoft: "It's not a bug, it's a feature "

Certain currency and mathematic symbols return 1 on ISNUMERIC.

Answer (score 2):

As per the manual page:

ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($). Also, it returns 1 for a range of datatypes like:

- int
- bigint
- smallint
- tinyint
- decimal

So while bigint accepts money values like `230,000`, a comma(,) also falls in the set of character which is considered to be a part of a numeric datatype similar to a dot(.) which is a character but is a part of the decimal datatype.