# SQL IsNumeric function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT IsNumeric('472369326D4')
```

is returning 1. Clearly, there is a aphabet `D` in the string. Why ?

Comment: This was some interested related reading: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76834/what-is-the-logic-behind-isnumeric-for-certain-special-characters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server's ISNUMERIC function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135878/sql-servers-isnumeric-function)

Comment: Also see [Why is ISNUMERIC(',') true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24053613/11683)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`472369326D4` is a valid `float` type. The `D4` is translated as adding four `0` values, effectively multiplying the value before the `D` character by `10000`.

Example Sql

```
SELECT cast('472369326D4' as float) 
SELECT cast('472369326D3' as float) 
SELECT cast('472369326D2' as float)
```

Output:

```
4723693260000
472369326000
47236932600
```

Comment: Hmm.. Thats very interesting. I will accept your answer. I was checking if this is Numeric and converting to BigInt which was failing . Something like SELECT CONVERT(bigInt , '472369326D4')

Answer (score 0):

You probably want logic like this:

```
(case when str not like '%[^0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end) as isNumeric
```

Or, if you want to allow decimals and negative signs the logic is a little more cumbersome:

```
(case when str not like '%.%.%' and str not like '%[^.0-9]%' and
           str not like '-%[^.0-9]%'
      then 1 else 0
 end)
```

I strongly recommend *not* using `isnumeric()`.  It produces strange results.  In addition to 'd', 'e' is allowed.

In SQL Server 2012+, you can try the following:

```
select x, isnumeric(x), try_convert(float, x)
from (values ('$'), ('$.'), ('-'), ('.')) v(x)
```

All of these return `1` for `isnumeric`, but `NULL` for the conversion, meaning that you cannot convert the value to a float.  (You can run the code in SQL Server 2008 with `convert()` instead and watch the code fail.)