# Why does ISNUMERIC() state a Zip Code, which is a varchar data type, as numeric in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

From my understanding, and I am probably wrong here, but doesn't the ISNUMERIC() return a 1 if whatever we are looking at is a numeric data type? And since most zip codes are saved as varchar data types, shouldn't it then return a 0? I looked up the documentation and that's what it says there to me, what am I missing here? I get zip codes are numbers, but because they are saved as a string shouldn't that make a difference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, `ISNUMERIC()` looks at the actual values, not the data types. Yes, the documentation is confusing about this if you read it the wrong way. It's also kind of a naiive, so it's generally best to use something more like `TRY_CONVERT()` instead.

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) could indeed use better wording: "Determines whether an expression is a valid numeric type". PHP, for instance, has a similarly named function described as "Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is ISNUMERIC(',') true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053613/why-is-isnumeric-true)

Comment: Thank you all, it makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

`ISNUMERIC()` is specifically to look at *strings*, not at things already stored as numbers.

However, I don't recommend using it.  For instance, `'3.1e5'` is considered numeric.

Instead, use `try_convert()`:

```
try_convert(int, zip)
```

This returns `NULL` if the column cannot be converted.

Comment: In all fairness to your example, '3e5' *is* numeric. `select cast(3e5 as int)` works.